# How does having zero advantage help with identifiability?

Tags: reinforcement-learning, dqn, papers, d3qn

I am reading the [D3QN paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1511.06581.pdf) and they have the following paragraph -

> Equation (7) is unidentifiable in the sense that given $Q$ we cannot recover $V$ and $A$ uniquely. To see this, add a constant to $V(s; \theta, \beta)$ and subtract the same constant from $A(s, a; \theta, \alpha)$. This constant cancels out resulting in the same $Q$ value. This lack of identifiability is mirrored by poor practical performance when this equation is used directly.
>
> To address this issue of identifiability, we can force the advantage function estimator to have zero advantage at the chosen action.

How does making the advantage for the chosen action 0 (actually, it's a little larger than 0, cause we'll be using the mean instead of max operator), help the neural network learn accurate estimates of $V$ and $A$?